# The adsize and ad unit id must be set before loadEd is called error is occur in react native android app

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I  am using react-native-admob library  for implementing admob feature,It work well in iOS,But in android it shows the error "adsize and ad unit id must be set before loadEd is called".My code is

```
                   <AdMobBanner
                        bannerSize="smartBannerPortrait"
                        adUnitID={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "iOS App Id" : "android App Id" }
                        //testDeviceID="SIMULATOR"
                        adViewDidReceiveAd={this.didReceiveAd}
                       didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError}
                       />
```

Comment: issue is solved by using react-native admob 2.0 has an adSize property instead of bannerSize

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer